# Allow image to overflow horizontally in a div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a grid section in which I show posts and I display photos and text. However, no photos are the same size and that is inevitable so I try to make them the same size. I cut to the chase, the problem is the `width:auto;` stretches the image horizontally.

```
<div class="item_grid item2">
    <div class="panel">
        <div style="height:50px; overflow:hidden;">
            <h4 class="recent-post-header">
                <a href="#">Title</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div style="height:300px; overflow:hidden;">
            //Problem is Here 
            <img src="/Image" alt="img_preview" style="height:100%; width:auto; " /> /
        </div>

        <div style="height:100px; overflow:hidden">
            <div class="clearfix post_date">
                <span class="pull-left">DateCreated</span>
            </div>
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>
        <p><a href="#"> Read More <i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to allow the width of the image overflow and then hide it?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
<img src="/Image" alt="img_preview"  style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover" >
```

eventhoug ie doesnt support `object-fit`

Comment: Your answer is the copied version of mine.

Comment: Do you know of anything that can work in Edge and IE too?

Comment: u can use `<div style="height:300px;width:200px;background:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);background-size:cover"></div>` . much simpler and no need to use img tag

Answer (score 0):

Short and straightforward answers

```
style="height:100%; object-fit: cover;"
```